# Compute the limit of complex function given

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Compute the value of
$\displaystyle \lim_{z \to 0} \left(\dfrac{1}{z^2} - \dfrac{1}{\sin^2 z}\right)$

We have used expansion, but found no leadings. Also, we try to factorize, hoping the wonders of trigonometry identity here, but seems no lead. Could you help us?

Comment: turn it into a single fraction, and try to factor out a powers of z (sin(z) does have a factor of z from the power series) from both the numerator and denominator.

Comment: And then what is the next step?

Comment: Apply L'hopital's Rule twice after writing it as  a single fraction and then look at the series expansion.

Comment: assuming you dont want to apply l'hopital's, put it as a single fraction and write out the first couple terms of the expansions of the numerator and denominator.  $z^4$ can be factored from both, and then the limit is just the constant terms.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\dfrac1{z^2}-\dfrac1{\sin^2z}=\dfrac{\sin z-z}{z^3}\left(\dfrac{\sin z}z+1\right)\left(\dfrac z{\sin z}\right)^2$$

Now use [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion)